# User Authentication: Providing separate errors for invalid email/password entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, alert

In my Rails app I'm trying to produce a separate `flash.now[:alert]` for invalid `:email` and `:password`, respectively. So if a user enters the correct email but wrong password, the `:alert` warns the user of an invalid password and vice versa. Here's what I have in my SessionsController:

```
def create
  if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to user.profile, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
  elsif user.email != params[:email]
    session[:email] = @user.email
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid email. Try again!"
    render :action => 'new'
  else
    session[:password] = @user.password
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid password. Try again!"
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Rendering this gives me an undefined method for email. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but I always been of the opinion that it's good *not* to indicate when the username is correct but the password is not since that makes it possible for someone to figure out a valid username (through brute force, perhaps). I don't know how much of a security hole this is, probably not a big one, but I'd avoid doing this.

Comment: Great point, thanks! I'm probably not going to do this, just was curious as to what was wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, Stack Exchange uses something similar to my question. Their flash for incorrect user is "No account with this email found" while their flash for incorrect password is "Incorrect password". I wonder what they're doing (if anything is possible) to secure themselves from the potential hole you and @Mauricio mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: Obviously this is a really bad idea as an attacker could keep on trying emails until he found one that did match and then he could start trying passwords for this email he knows exists at your database, but you're asking, so it's up to you deciding to do this or not.

Your authenticate method obviously only returns the user if the email and password did match, change your authenticate method to return a boolean and a user if there is any available. It would look somewhat like this:

```
def authenticate(email, password)
  u = first(:conditions => {:email => email, :state => 'active'})
  u && u.authenticated?(password) ? [true, u] : [false, u]
end
```

Then, at your controller:

```
def create
  result , user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if result 
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to user.profile, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
  elsif user
    session[:email] = @user.email
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid email. Try again!"
    render :action => 'new'
  else
    session[:password] = @user.password
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid password. Try again!"
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

And this should work.